# I've started a new job in a different state, but am not licenced, what can I do?

Tags: recruitment, united-states

tl;dr (summary) I was applied for a job in Illinois. I was offered and accepted a job. However, I'm not licensed to practice in Illinois. Company has put my job on hold even though I'm allowed to practice as long as there's a licensed clinician on staff. How do I get them to let me start while I'm waiting to get my Illinois license?

---

I live in Michigan and applied for a position in Illinois. I went through extensive interview process at 1 of the top hospitals in the US. The recruiters actually are employees of the hospital.

My initial interview was with the recruiter, followed by 2 department heads. Prior to my face to face with one of the department heads, my recruiter asked me to drop off a copy of my resume and license to practice. My license clearly states that I'm licensed in Michigan. I've been in practice for 20 years.

I was offered a position and signed my acceptance letter. I assumed everything was verified. The day I'm ready to start, my recruiter asks me for a copy of my Illinois license to practice.

I'm not licensed to practice in Illinois. I find out what I need to do to get licensed. Keep in mind that's a whole ordeal within itself.  I drive to the licensing department located in Springfield. I'm informed by the gentleman processing my license (he provided me with a copy of the law as well) that as long as I'm not engaging in private practice and there is a licensed clinician at that facility the law states I am allowed to work under that clinician.

I don't mind taking the test. It's just a time factor. The hospital has held my position since February. On 3 different occasions, I've emailed the recruiter inquiring about this law but she has not responded.

I relocated to start work, started the process to take the test but haven't been able to start my job because of this licensing issue. I really want this job. I don't feel I should be punished by losing my job because the recruiter failed to verify licensure.

What do I do now? Do I contact someone in HR. I don't want to get anyone in trouble but I also don't want to lose my job because someone else failed to do their job. PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: I added a summary and reformatted the text into paragraphs.  The changes are currently under review. If you don't agree with them, please revert or further edit them.

Comment: My gosh man. You are a Dr! Take some personal responsibility!

Comment: If someone's ignoring your emails then either call them or go see them face-to-face. Whatever outcome you're after - them to let you start work with the correct supervision, or to use whatever influence they have to hurry along your licence, or reassure you that you won't lose your job - you need to get communication going first. As to whose fault, you can just say there was a mix-up for now and only point fingers if you have to, but it's more important to fix the job start than worry about that I'd think. If you had to suck it up & accept the blame for the licence to save your job would you?

Comment: @agenovese - I may be assuming here, but given the OP has chosen lulu as a name, don't think it's a man

Comment: You should get licensed to practice in Illinois.  The fact you don't get response about the clause of allowing you to practice under somebody else, tells me they are not interested in you using that option.  Of course in my personal opinion I would have walked into the office, where HR was, the day after I talked the licensing department.  Does it really take 4 months to do that?

Comment: OP may not be a physician, but a psychologist, therapist, etc.

Comment: What's the penalty for practicing without a license? Prison time? You'd better get things into perspective and realize losing this job might be the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

So as I understand it:

- You are a doctor with 20 years experience
- You are knowing licenced in one particular state
- You have got a new job in a different state, which you had a good idea needed their own license
- In the five month process you emailed three times about licencing, but took no other steps
- You didn't find out about the steps required to be licensed in the new state until you started
- You are wondering how not to get someone in trouble to allow you to work without the license

I think you have take responsibility for your own (lack of) actions here.  In a situation like this I would have known exactly what was involved BEFORE I applied to the new job, to understand  what effort was involved in such a move.

You need to prioritise getting your licence, and make sure the new job knows BOTH your issue, and what you can do in the mean time, but if you need to not work until you are licenced, you need to figure if that is something you can absorb.

Next time make the effort and know what you're getting into.

Comment: Er, no.  My point is that as an experienced professional they had a reasonable expectation that they would be unable to work (and could have taken steps to avoid it).  The OP isn't being "punished", they do not have a licence to practise in the state (at least without another doctor being present as they work, which the employer isn't doing as it probably is the same as employing a med student).

Comment: I'll also guess there is a clause in their contract signed by the OP stating they are licensed to practise in the state.   Passing the required tests takes time and effort (and likely money),  if the employer was arranging this there would have been a ton of messages flying.  I just started a new job which has a week long orientation in a different place to where I work,  the number of emails with instructions and dates things needed to be done was amazing,  and this isn't a mandated thing in my industry.